# How to edit this 3d Model?

Tags: modeling

I am a bit of a noob but I need help with this!https://free3d.com/3d-model/ironman-rigged-original-model--98611.html
I was wondering how to cut/crop/whatever those little annoying balls from the model?

Thank you for your time and help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Those are controls for the rig that moves the character. Deleting them would limit the functions of the rig. You can hide the entire rig with <kbd>H</kbd> if you want them to disappear form the viewport, but they won't show up when rendering, so I would just leave them be.

Answer (score 0):

"Those little annoying balls" seem to be a part of the rigging. This means they can be used to move and animate the figure. If you remove them, you won't be able to animate the way the author intended.

If you don't need to animate, maybe you can safely delete them. But it might be a better idea to hide them, if they bother you now. Just select the ball (right-click) and click the eye next to it in the outliner:

[image: Screenshot]

They will be gone! But you can always get them back by clicking the eye again.

Comment: I'm kinda new to this but how did you access the window where you can find the rigging and "the annoying little balls?"

Comment: @PedroDaSilveira In the default view, the outliner appears on the top right. When you select the object, it will be highlighted in the outliner. If it is parented to an object, you will see a circular highlight next to the object that is the parent. Click the (+) on that object to view it's contents.